# The meaning of a sentence written by Lovecraft

Tags: sentence-meaning

I cannot figure out the meaning of the following sentence:

> The green of the backyard gives way to overgrown flowers toward the side of the house.

I know every word, but even after having reread it a couple of times, I still don't catch it.

This a sentence from Lovecraft's *Mansions of Madness - What Lies Within (Script)*

Comment: What don't you understand? Gives way?  Toward?

Comment: It's always helpful if you say which particular bit don't you understand. Is it **give way to** - 2. Be replaced or superseded by. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/give_way

Comment: It sounds like it's describing someone walking from the back garden of a house (which has a big green, grassy lawn) round to the side of the house. What is the bit that's causing you trouble? A few surrounding sentences for context could be useful too.

Comment: So does this mean that partially overgrown flowers are growing on the green or that they blend toward the side of the house?

Answer (score 2):

Going (or looking) from the backyard to the front, or at least the side, of the house, there's a visual change from the unrelieved green of the grass in back to a riot of color at the side because the flowers haven't had any attention and have outgrown their space.

Answer (score 2):

See [*give way*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/give_way):

> 2 (give way to) Be replaced or superseded by.
>   *Alan's discomfort **gave way** to anger*

In your example, this indicates a change or transformation in the landscape, probably gradual, between the green backyard (maybe lawn and trees) and the multicolored flowers.